# mysqldump dump file size

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I have used mysql-administrator to back up my mediawiki and bugzilla database.
Now there is an issue  with charsets I can't fix.
So I deciced to try mysqldump
with `-single-transaction --routines --triggers`.  My database is a mix of inno and mysiam tables.

I am confused about the different size of the dump files.
While the mysqldump is ~150 MB, the mysqladmin file is ~220MB.
I cannot explain this, and I can't analyze the dump files, it  is too big for my notepad.

I have two questions:

1. What's the cause of the different sizes?
2. Anyone any suggestions about my options to backup?

Comment: Maybe it is possible with the command `more` in a cmd-window to view the first pages of the dump file. There are free viewers for large files.

Answer (score 1):

It was because mysqladmin didn't compress the the data.
when you open it, you will see nice query and code. and also easy to study.

if after compress, the query will stick in 1 line. and hard to study.